# Unable to access Nginx installed on Google Cloud VM

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have installed Nginx on Google Cloud Ubuntu 18. The service status check says that the service has successfully started. I am using default configuration. HTTP and HTTPS are enabled in the firewall setting.

Any idea on what else I need to check?

Comment: try shutting off the firewall

Comment: @RafiHenig Tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @RafiHenig for providing the hint. Actually I had enabled HTTP and HTTPS in GCP VM firewall but looks like you have to enable it in Ubuntu as well. Ran the following command and it worked.

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```